# sql query to reduce amount of data

Tags: oracle, plsqldeveloper

[image]

I am a new oracle developer and I have no clue how to do it:
so I need to create a query in oracle that reduce the amount of my returned data 
what I have is 2 records for the same purpose

In the first record I have

```
id1 = A and id2 = B
```

and in the second I have

```
id1 = B and id2 = A
```

So I need a query that return just one record for each 2 records saved in the database have this combination.

I tried to do inner select or try to read from the same table twice and filter the results but with no success.

Comment: Please post some sample data, expected result and what you tried so far

Comment: you need to provide more information, sample data, expected results etc.

Comment: i did add a screen shot that explain how the duplication is taking place and i want for every combination of those two ids to get just 1 record

Comment: Data and queries should be added as formated text, not images, so that people can use them to build an example and help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without having details about your table structure or the query which generated the two record result set, I can offer the following query:

```
SELECT LEAST(id1, id2)    AS id1,
       GREATEST(id1, id2) AS id2
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY LEAST(id1, id2),
         GREATEST(id1, id2)
```

Comment: i did add a screen shot that explain how the duplication is taking place and i want for every combination of those two ids to get just 1 record

Comment: @Neeldz Your query is _requesting_ that this duplication take place.  But my answer actually still stands to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well your need, you can try the following:

```
with test(id1, id2) as (
    select 1, 2 from dual union all
    select 2, 1 from dual
)
select least(id1, id2), greatest(id1, id2)
from test
group by least(id1, id2), greatest(id1, id2)
```

Comment: This looks much like my answer.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen:  I only saw that your answer had not group by, so I thought to give mine; now I see your edit and I understand that your first version was due to the unclear question. Sorry, I'm removing soon

Comment: @Neeldz: Read the above comments and please accept Tim's answer; . I'm going to remove mine

Comment: @Aleksej i did accept Tim's answer its just i wanted to be fair since his response had duplication in the returned results . anw thank you both for your help it was really in place